# How to force end of some admonitions in a RST file

Tags: documentation, restructuredtext, documentation-generation

I have a note in a reStructuredText formatted text that will be placed between a point of a list, and its sublist. The problem is that the note include the sublist.

---

Here is an extract of the file:

```
3. Select build parameters on the `CI              
   <https://website.com/CI>`_ and run it on your
   remote  branch.
 
.. note::

   The text of the note.

   a. If the failure is not related to your changes, say so in the pull request
      comments.
   b. Then, make the appropriate fixes.

 4. Wait for comments or approval. If modifications are requested by the
    comments, consider implementing them.
```

---

When I compile it, `a.` and `b.` are included **into** the note. But I don't want that. Is there a way to force the note to end after `The text of the note.` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is wrong. See the comments for why. See [Steve Piercy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63170569/11138259) for a correct one.

---

Probably something like the following:

```
3. Select build parameters on the `CI
   <https://website.com/CI>`_ and run it on your
   remote  branch.

.. note::

   The text of the note.

..

   a. If the failure is not related to your changes, say so in the pull request
      comments.
   b. Then, make the appropriate fixes.

4. Wait for comments or approval. If modifications are requested by the
comments, consider implementing them.
```

Comment: This answer is not correct because the comment `..` breaks the list nesting and turns item 4 into a paragraph instead of the desired list item.

Comment: Yes, seems like I was a bit too quick in posting this answer. I would delete, but I can't right now, since it's the accepted answer.

Comment: @Apitronix, if possible set Steve's answer as the accepted one, so I can delete this one, since it has obvious flaws.

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace has meaning in reStructuredText.  You need to indent appropriately.  Also for nested lists, a blank line is necessary when the nesting level changes.

```
3.  Select build parameters on the `CI <https://website.com/CI>`_ and run it on your remote branch.

    .. note::

        The text of the note.

    a.  If the failure is not related to your changes, say so in the pull request comments.
    b.  Then, make the appropriate fixes.

4.  Wait for comments or approval. If modifications are requested by the comments, consider implementing them.
```

Note that I indent 4 spaces and do not use line breaks within a sentence.  Docs are not code, and do not need to be wrapped.

Comment: Off-topic, but still curious: what would be the advantages / drawbacks of doing line breaks or not? (If it can be answered in a comment, maybe with a link, otherwise nevermind).

Comment: The last time I used a line break in narrative text was on a typewriter. Word processors and editors soft wrap text just fine. If you hard-wrap your docs, then update them, the diff is usually awful and time-consuming to review. With one sentence per line, diffs are much easier to see. It is also easier to write translations when there is a complete sentence on a single line.

Comment: I had in mind that the reason was closer to reStructuredText itself. But yes. Of course. I cursed at this hard-wrap/diff issue many times, but somehow blacked out the thought of enabling soft-wrap in my editor for this file type only. Thanks. Thanks for Pyramid.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be an indentation problem.

If the note is related to the `3.` point, [this answer seems to be good.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63170301/11547112)

Else, if the note is related to a sublist element, you need to indent one more time the note.

```
3. Select build parameters on the `CI
   <https://website.com/CI>`_ and run it on your
   remote  branch.

   .. note::

      The text of the note.

   a. If the failure is not related to your changes, say so in the pull request
      comments.
   b. Then, make the appropriate fixes.

4. Wait for comments or approval. If modifications are requested by the
   comments, consider implementing them.
```